# Send AJAX request for Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use autocomplete in jquery in that i am sending request on page to get the data but that is not working for me.Please help me in this

**jQuery**

```
var addInput = function() {
  var inputHTML = "<input name='search' value='' class='test' maxlength='20' />";
  $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");
  $("input.test:last").focus();
};

$("input#addButton").click(addInput);
var options = {
  source: "abc.html",
  minLength: 2
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test" ).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working? Any output on the console? Please also post all the relevant code.

Comment: request is not getting sent on my page that is abc.html

Comment: @PoojaDubey You have an error. Lemme add the answer.

Comment: same i have done but that is not working

Comment: @PoojaDubey I have updated my answer. Kindly check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the error in the line I have said.

```
var addInput = function() {
  var inputHTML = "<input name='search' value='' class='test' maxlength='20' />";
  $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");
  $("input.test:last").focus();
};
$("input#addButton").click(addInput);
}); // This is wrong. It should be }

var options = {
  source: "abc.html",
  minLength: 2
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test" ).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
  });
});
```

Just remove that above line, having:

```
var addInput = function() {
  var inputHTML = "<input name='search' value='' class='test' maxlength='20' />";
  $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");
  $("input.test:last").focus();
};
$("input#addButton").click(addInput);

var options = {
  source: "abc.html",
  minLength: 2
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test" ).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
  });
});
```

If the above fails too, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test" ).on('focus', function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: "abc.html",
      minLength: 2
    });
  });
  $("input#addButton").click(function () {
    var inputHTML = "<input name='search' value='' class='test' maxlength='20' />";
    $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");
    $("input.test:last").focus();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What issue i have seen here:

1. You are trying to bind event before dom ready.
2. You have an extra closing tag of unknown.
3. You are binding an event on an element which is not in the DOM but after some user interaction.

---

I can see an extra closing in here:

```
$("input#addButton").click(addInput);
}); // <----------------------------------this one don't know which one
    //------------------------------------but it should not have to be here.
```

another thing i would suggest you to use it this way:

```
var addInput = function() {
  var inputHTML = "<input name='search' value='' class='test' maxlength='20' />";
  var options = {
    source: "abc.html",
    minLength: 2
  };
  $(inputHTML).appendTo("form#myForm");
  $("input.test:last").focus().autocomplete(options); // <----initialize it here.
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#addButton").click(addInput); // bind the event here.
});
```